# Django - Running custom method on syndb command

Tags: django, django-syncdb

I'm wondering if there is a way to run a custom method when syncdb is executed.
What I am trying to accomplish is to load a mail template into the database. As I need nearly the same template in multiple entries in the db, I don't want to place it in the initial_data file.

I've searched the django docs and the web, but couldn't find any solution for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the `post_syncdb` signal?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_syncdb

Connect a handler to the signal and run whatever you wish in your function.

Well, it might work in your case, it might not. `post_syncdb` is called after table creation and sent to all apps, so if you want one method that handles all default data creation, you'd have to use something like the following snippet to detect if the signal is for the last app in the list to ensure your tables exist :P.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1988/

Well, it's an idea. Enjoy!

Comment: Looks quite like what i need, but doesn't seem to work atm. still struggling a bit with the registration of the signal handler. I'll give you feedback later if it worked. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, your solution works. But it's not exactly what i need because the `syncdb_signal` takes place before the installations of the fixtures. But you pointed me to the right direction. I'll now create save handlers for the model to update the content of the templates after the installtion of the fixtures. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Grave, thanks for accepting this as an answer :) Can I ask what you did? You mean the post/pre_save signals?

Comment: Actually, I think you're supposed to answer your own question so others with the same problem can find your solution, I am curious after all.